# Reading Firebase Auth Error Thrown (Firebase 3.x and Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm having trouble figuring out how to read the FIRAuthErrorNameKey in the new version of Firebase.  The following is what I have so far, but the "let errorCode = FIRAuthErrorNameKey" line is incorrect.  From reading the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/errors) I also tried accessing the error code from the userInfo, but was unsuccessful and am out of ideas.

```
 // Send request to Firebase to add user to register user
 FIRAuth.auth()?.createUserWithEmail(emailTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!, completion: { (user, error) in

        // Check for errors and respond to user accordingly.
        if error != nil {

            let errorCode = FIRAuthErrorNameKey

            switch errorCode {

            case "FIRAuthErrorCodeEmailAlreadyInUse":

                // Add logic accordingly

            case ...:

               // Add logic accordingly

            case default:

              // Add logic accordingly
            }
        }
 })
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Try this. This works for me. Also, after pasting this into your project. If you need to see all the `FIRAuthErrorCode` codes. Hover your mouse over `.ErrorCodeInvalidEmail` then press your left mouse button and it will show you the rest.

If you have any problems let me know and ill try to help you. Good luck!

```
        FIRAuth.auth()?.createUserWithEmail(email, password: password) { (user, error) in

            if error != nil {

                if let errCode = FIRAuthErrorCode(rawValue: error!._code) {

                    switch errCode {
                        case .ErrorCodeInvalidEmail:
                            print("invalid email")
                        case .ErrorCodeEmailAlreadyInUse:
                            print("in use")
                        default:
                            print("Create User Error: \(error!)")
                    }
                }

            } else {
                print("all good... continue")
            }
        }
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!  Thanks for the help and thinking about how to find the error codes.  Unfortunately I could never figure out how to use the String error codes on the Firebase Guide page (https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/errors), but this does the trick!

Comment: Firebase has now removed the `FIR` in front of their calls. So it will just be `AuthErrorCode`

Comment: They also seemed to have renamed the error enums slightly. If you type `case .` then you will see all of them.

Comment: The updated code (2024) should look like `if let nsError = error as? NSError` `guard let errorCode = AuthErrorCode(_nsError: nsError)` `switch errorCode.error` and then match the case just using a constant (`.credentialAlreadyInUse`, ...)

Answer (score 25):

None of answers seem to be up-to-date, here's what I do currently on Swift 3.x, FirebaseAuth 4.0.0

```
Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, error) in

        if let error = error as NSError? {

            guard let errorCode = AuthErrorCode(rawValue: error.code) else {

                print("there was an error logging in but it could not be matched with a firebase code")
                return

            }

            switch errorCode {

            case .invalidEmail:

                print("invalid email")

                //...
```

Comment: This is the right answer, firebase provides an Error and we should cast to NSError

Answer (score 11):

Firebase has changed the code a bit, and if you are new to Firebase it will take you a bit of time getting your code working.  I have spent almost 3 hours figuring out what's going on.  Here's how it looks now:

```
Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user: User?, error) in

        if error != nil {
        // Handle the error (i.e notify the user of the error)

            if let errCode = AuthErrorCode(rawValue: error!._code) {

                switch errCode {
                case .invalidEmail:
                    print("invalid email")
                case .emailAlreadyInUse:
                    print("in use")
                default:
                    print("Other error!")
                }

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 8):

I followed the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37902747/4833705) which worked but the `switch cases` changed and the data type is `AuthErrorCode`. Here are the updated `switch cases`. There are 77 of them that I got [from here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Enums/AuthErrorCode):

```
Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: emailTextField.text!, password: password) { [weak self] (user, error) in

    if let error = error {

        if let errCode = AuthErrorCode(rawValue: error._code) {

             self?.alertUser(of: errCode)
        }
        return
    }
}

func alertUser(of errorCode: AuthErrorCode) {
    
    switch errorCode {
        
    case .accountExistsWithDifferentCredential:
        print("0- Indicates account linking is required.")
    case .adminRestrictedOperation:
        print("1- Indicates that the operation is admin restricted.")
    case .appNotAuthorized:
        print("2- Indicates the App is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication with the provided API Key.")
    case .appNotVerified:
        print("3- Indicates that the app could not be verified by Firebase during phone number authentication.")
    case .appVerificationUserInteractionFailure:
        print("4- Indicates a general failure during the app verification flow.")
    case .captchaCheckFailed:
        print("5- Indicates that the reCAPTCHA token is not valid.")
    case .credentialAlreadyInUse:
        print("6- Indicates an attempt to link with a credential that has already been linked with a different Firebase account")
    case .customTokenMismatch:
        print("7- Indicates the service account and the API key belong to different projects.")
    case .dynamicLinkNotActivated:
        print("8- Indicates that a Firebase Dynamic Link is not activated.")
    case .emailAlreadyInUse:
        print("9- Indicates the email used to attempt a sign up is already in use.")
    case .emailChangeNeedsVerification:
        print("10- Indicates that the a verifed email is required to changed to.")
    case .expiredActionCode:
        print("11- Indicates the OOB code is expired.")
    case .gameKitNotLinked:
        print("12- Indicates that the GameKit framework is not linked prior to attempting Game Center signin.")
    case .internalError:
        print("13- Indicates an internal error occurred.")
    case .invalidActionCode:
        print("15- Indicates the OOB code is invalid.")
    case .invalidAPIKey:
        print("15- Indicates an invalid API key was supplied in the request.")
    case .invalidAppCredential:
        print("16- Indicates that an invalid APNS device token was used in the verifyClient request.")
    case .invalidClientID:
        print("17- Indicates that the clientID used to invoke a web flow is invalid.")
    case .invalidContinueURI:
        print("18- Indicates that the domain specified in the continue URI is not valid.")
    case .invalidCredential:
        print("19- Indicates the IDP token or requestUri is invalid.")
    case .invalidCustomToken:
        print("20- Indicates a validation error with the custom token.")
    case .invalidDynamicLinkDomain:
        print("21- Indicates that the Firebase Dynamic Link domain used is either not configured or is unauthorized for the current project.")
    case .invalidEmail:
        print("22- Indicates the email is invalid.")
    case .invalidMessagePayload:
        print("23- Indicates that there are invalid parameters in the payload during a 'send password reset email' attempt.")
    case .invalidMultiFactorSession:
        print("24- Indicates that the multi factor session is invalid.")
    case .invalidPhoneNumber:
        print("25- Indicates that an invalid phone number was provided in a call to verifyPhoneNumber:completion:.")
    case .invalidProviderID:
        print("26- Represents the error code for when the given provider id for a web operation is invalid.")
    case .invalidRecipientEmail:
        print("27- Indicates that the recipient email is invalid.")
    case .invalidSender:
        print("28- Indicates that the sender email is invalid during a “send password reset email” attempt.")
    case .invalidUserToken:
        print("29- Indicates user’s saved auth credential is invalid, the user needs to sign in again.")
    case .invalidVerificationCode:
        print("30- Indicates that an invalid verification code was used in the verifyPhoneNumber request.")
    case .invalidVerificationID:
        print("31- Indicates that an invalid verification ID was used in the verifyPhoneNumber request.")
    case .keychainError:
        print("32- Indicates an error occurred while attempting to access the keychain.")
    case .localPlayerNotAuthenticated:
        print("33- Indicates that the local player was not authenticated prior to attempting Game Center signin.")
    case .maximumSecondFactorCountExceeded:
        print("34- Indicates that the maximum second factor count is exceeded.")
    case .malformedJWT:
        print("35- Raised when a JWT fails to parse correctly. May be accompanied by an underlying error describing which step of the JWT parsing process failed.")
    case .missingAndroidPackageName:
        print("36- Indicates that the android package name is missing when the androidInstallApp flag is set to true.")
    case .missingAppCredential:
        print("37- Indicates that the APNS device token is missing in the verifyClient request.")
    case .missingAppToken:
        print("38- Indicates that the APNs device token could not be obtained. The app may not have set up remote notification correctly, or may fail to forward the APNs device token to FIRAuth if app delegate swizzling is disabled.")
    case .missingContinueURI:
        print("39- Indicates that a continue URI was not provided in a request to the backend which requires one.")
    case .missingClientIdentifier:
        print("40- Indicates an error for when the client identifier is missing.")
    case .missingEmail:
        print("41- Indicates that an email address was expected but one was not provided.")
    case .missingIosBundleID:
        print("42- Indicates that the iOS bundle ID is missing when a iOS App Store ID is provided.")
    case .missingMultiFactorSession:
        print("43- Indicates that the multi factor session is missing.")
    case .missingOrInvalidNonce:
        print("44- Indicates that the nonce is missing or invalid.")
    case .missingPhoneNumber:
        print("45- Indicates that a phone number was not provided in a call to verifyPhoneNumber:completion.")
    case .missingVerificationCode:
        print("46- Indicates that the phone auth credential was created with an empty verification code.")
    case .missingVerificationID:
        print("47- Indicates that the phone auth credential was created with an empty verification ID.")
    case .missingMultiFactorInfo:
        print("48- Indicates that the multi factor info is missing.")
    case .multiFactorInfoNotFound:
        print("49- Indicates that the multi factor info is not found.")
    case .networkError:
        print("50- Indicates a network error occurred (such as a timeout, interrupted connection, or unreachable host). These types of errors are often recoverable with a retry. The NSUnderlyingError field in the NSError.userInfo dictionary will contain the error encountered.")
    case.noSuchProvider:
        print("51- Indicates an attempt to unlink a provider that is not linked.")
    case .notificationNotForwarded:
        print("52- Indicates that the app fails to forward remote notification to FIRAuth.")
    case .nullUser:
        print("53- Indicates that a non-null user was expected as an argmument to the operation but a null user was provided.")
    case .operationNotAllowed:
        print("54- Indicates the administrator disabled sign in with the specified identity provider.")
    case .providerAlreadyLinked:
        print("55- Indicates an attempt to link a provider to which the account is already linked.")
    case .quotaExceeded:
        print("56- Indicates that the quota of SMS messages for a given project has been exceeded.")
    case .rejectedCredential:
        print("57- Indicates that the credential is rejected because it’s misformed or mismatching.")
    case .requiresRecentLogin:
        print("58- Indicates the user has attemped to change email or password more than 5 minutes after signing in.")
    case .secondFactorAlreadyEnrolled:
        print("59- Indicates that the second factor is already enrolled.")
    case .secondFactorRequired:
        print("60- Indicates that the second factor is required for signin.")
    case .sessionExpired:
        print("61- Indicates that the SMS code has expired.")
    case .tooManyRequests:
        print("62- Indicates that too many requests were made to a server method.")
    case .unauthorizedDomain:
        print("63- Indicates that the domain specified in the continue URL is not whitelisted in the Firebase console.")
    case .unsupportedFirstFactor:
        print("64- Indicates that the first factor is not supported.")
    case .unverifiedEmail:
        print("65- Indicates that the email is required for verification.")
    case .userDisabled:
        print("66- Indicates the user’s account is disabled on the server.")
    case .userMismatch:
        print("67- Indicates that an attempt was made to reauthenticate with a user which is not the current user.")
    case .userNotFound:
        print("68- Indicates the user account was not found.")
    case .userTokenExpired:
        print("69- Indicates the saved token has expired, for example, the user may have changed account password on another device. The user needs to sign in again on the device that made this request.")
    case .weakPassword:
        print("70- Indicates an attempt to set a password that is considered too weak.")
    case .webContextAlreadyPresented:
        print("71- Indicates that an attempt was made to present a new web context while one was already being presented.")
    case .webContextCancelled:
        print("72- Indicates that the URL presentation was cancelled prematurely by the user.")
    case .webInternalError:
        print("73- Indicates that an internal error occurred within a SFSafariViewController or WKWebView.")
    case .webNetworkRequestFailed:
        print("74- Indicates that a network request within a SFSafariViewController or WKWebView failed.")
    case .wrongPassword:
        print("75- Indicates the user attempted sign in with a wrong password.")
    case .webSignInUserInteractionFailure:
        print("76- Indicates a general failure during a web sign-in flow.")
    default:
        print("77- Unknown error occurred")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The firebase seems to have updated and the code that worked for me is as follows:

```
if let err = err as NSError? {
    let errCode = AuthErrorCode(_nsError: err)
    errorDes = errCode.localizedDescription
    switch errCode.code {
        case .accountExistsWithDifferentCredential, .credentialAlreadyInUse, .emailAlreadyInUse:
            errorMsg = "Account already exists"
        case .missingEmail:
            errorMsg = "Email is missing"
        case .weakPassword:
            errorMsg = "Password is weak."
        default:
            errorMsg = "Failed to create user"
    }
    return
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the snippet it seems like you are trying to use the error code and not the FIRAuthErrorNameKey in your switch. In that case what you want to use is the error code of the NSError object returned in the callback.
Use:

```
let errorCode = error.code
```

This way your errorCode variable will contain the error code that was returned and you can proceed with your error handling logic.

Comment: Thanks for the idea to get me on the right track.  This technically didn't work with my setup above because .code returns an int.  It would work by re-working my code to match the error codes.  I can't find these in the Firebase guides, but if you follow the approach outlined by the_pantless_coder to see all the error codes in the other answer you can get the int error codes there.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i dont know if this helps but you can do this also:

```
let errcode = FIRAuthErrorCode(rawValue: error!._code)
    if errcode == FIRAuthErrorCode.errorCodeRequiresRecentLogin{

            //do error handling here

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using Xamarin.iOS

You need to catch an NSErrorException which is the c# wrapped NSError

```
  try
  {
    await auth.CreateUserAsync(email, password);
  }
  catch (NSErrorException e)
  {
    throw new Exception(e.Error.LocalizedDescription);
  }
```