# Firebase 3.6.0 (Auth) - Detecting the specific error using Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to work out how to detect a certain error. Say the login failed, I want to check if the error was say the account entered doesn't exist, and then tell the viewer that. Same goes with all of the other errors if possible.

In Parse I would check if the error.code was equal to a certain number, not sure if it's the same or anything similar to Firebase.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37449919/reading-firebase-auth-error-thrown-firebase-3-x-and-swift Question answered here, same code dravidian posted

Comment: I couldn't find anything while searching beforehand, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Rialcom that's not the same answer .In swift3 you need to access your err as `._code`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this:-

```
if let errCode = FIRAuthErrorCode(rawValue: err!._code) {

                switch errCode {
                case .errorCodeInvalidEmail:
                    print("invalid email")
                case .errorCodeEmailAlreadyInUse:
                    print("in use")
                default:
                    print("Other error!")
                }

            }
```

Where **err** is the received error from firebase

Answer (score 5):

Here is new format with notification

```
Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user: User?, error) in

if error != nil {

    if let errCode = AuthErrorCode(rawValue: error!._code) {

        switch errCode {
        case .invalidEmail:

            print("invalid email")
            // Create an alert message
            let alertMessage = UIAlertController(title: "Invalid Email", message: "Please check the entered email address", preferredStyle: .alert)
            // Attach an action on alert message
            alertMessage.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
                alertMessage.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }))
            // Display the alert message
            self.present(alertMessage, animated: true, completion: nil)

        case .emailAlreadyInUse:

            print("in use")
            // Create an alert message
            let alertMessage = UIAlertController(title: "Existed Email", message: "The email existed in our database, login instead of registering", preferredStyle: .alert)
            // Attach an action on alert message
            alertMessage.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
                alertMessage.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            }))
            // Display the alert message
            self.present(alertMessage, animated: true, completion: nil)

            case .weakPassword:

                print("password is weak")
                // Create an alert message
                let alertMessage = UIAlertController(title: "Password is weak", message: "Use upper and lower characters along with numbers", preferredStyle: .alert)
                // Attach an action on alert message
                alertMessage.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
                    alertMessage.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                }))
                // Display the alert message
                self.present(alertMessage, animated: true, completion: nil)

        default:
            print("Other error!")
        }

    }
}
```