# SwiftUI Firebase How To Do Custom Error Handling

Tags: firebase, error-handling, swiftui

So I'm creating an app that used Firebase as the backend and I want to display the user-specific custom error messages instead of the built-in firebase error messages. How would I do this?

```
func signIn(withEmail email: String, password: String){
        
        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (result,err) in
            if let err = err {
            
                print("DEBUG: Failed to login: \(err.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
            self.userSession = result?.user
            self.fetchUser()
            
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. Are you asking how to `print` a different error? Show an alert in the UI? What have you tried so far? What problems did you encounter?

Comment: yeah i guess i wasn't super specific, for example if there was a network error I want to be able to alert it to the user (in any way) that it was specifically a network error instead of just "error"

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you look up "SwiftUI alert"? You can provide any arbitrary text you want -- you aren't just stuck saying "Error".

Comment: i know how to alert it to the user I'm just saying how would I be able to know which specific error that the user has encountered. Because I've looked through the Firebase error documentation and there's nothing

Comment: ```err.localizedDescription``` gives the built-in firebase error message but I want to display my own custom specific error message based on the specific error that the user is experiencing

Comment: So are you looking for a list of possible errors that you can map to your own error messages?

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37902747/560942

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the Authentication error codes are listed in the [Authentication Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/errors).

Here's a quick snippet of how to handle the errors and present your own error message.

```
Auth.auth().signIn....() { (auth, error) in //some signIn function
  if let x = error {
      let err = x as NSError
      switch err.code {
      case AuthErrorCode.wrongPassword.rawValue:
          print("wrong password, you big dummy")
      case AuthErrorCode.invalidEmail.rawValue:
          print("invalid email - duh")
      case AuthErrorCode.accountExistsWithDifferentCredential.rawValue:
          print("the account already exists")
      default:
          print("unknown error: \(err.localizedDescription)")
      }
  } else {
      if let _ = auth?.user {
          print("authd")
      } else {
          print("no authd user")
      }
  }
}
```

There are many ways to code this so this is just an example.